# How to send URL request

Tags: chromium, urlrequest

I'm developing a new module in Chromium solution, in which I want to create and send a request to specific server. I've tried to implement this in many way: call Send() method of URL request directly, use URL fetcher, send via IPC route... but no one could be successful.

Comment: Please share the code you used, and ask a direct question.  I'm not even sure if you're writing a web site, extension, or a custom Chromium build.

Comment: I'm developing my own Chrome browser with some enhancement in download features.

Comment: So, in Download Sequence: [http://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/downloadmanagersequences], i try to send another request to server after get first response from server (in responsestarted use case) by making URLfetcher like that:

Comment: URLFetcher fetcher; fetcher.Create(...); fetcher.Start(),... and send this request to server. After that, I can't get server response from server to current render process.